# Longtable has two captions/heads on the next page

Tags: captions, page-breaking, longtable

Here is a demo:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}

  \setlength\LTpre{5em}
  \setlength\LTpost{5em}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font={singlespacing,small}}
\captionsetup[table]{position=top,skip={0pt}}
\captionsetup[longtable]{skip=0pt}


\title{test}
\begin{document}
This is a test table.  % repeat the paragraph to make the table at the end of a page.

This is a test table.

This is a test table.

This is a test table.

This is a test table.

This is a test table.

This is a test table.

This is a test table.

This is a test table.

This is a test table.

This is a test table.

This is a test table.

This is a test table.

This is a test table.

This is a test table.

This is a test table.

This is a test table.

This is a test table.

This is a test table.

This is a test table.

This is a test table.

This is a test table.

This is a test table.

This is a test table.

This is a test table.

\begin{longtable}[]{@{}cl@{}}
\caption{test table test table test tabletest tabletest tabletest tabletest tabletest tabletest tabletest tabletest tabletest tabletest table}\tabularnewline
\toprule
col1 & col2\tabularnewline
\midrule
\endhead
1 & 2\tabularnewline
1 & 2\tabularnewline
1 & 2\tabularnewline
1 & 2\tabularnewline
1 & 2\tabularnewline
1 & 2\tabularnewline
1 & 2\tabularnewline
1 & 2\tabularnewline
1 & 2\tabularnewline
1 & 2\tabularnewline
1 & 2\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}


End of the document.
\end{document}
```

The table starts at the end of a page, but both captions goes to the next page. [image: see the output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry it's a bug, the easiest workaround is to put

```
\clearpage
```

before the table.

Comment: One can also add the patch from https://github.com/davidcarlisle/dpctex/issues/8.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes I suspected it was that